# How can Namor be the first mutant if there are much older ones?

Tags: marvel, chronology

I saw several mentions on SFF that Namor was the first mutant.

Yet, from [ComicVine](http://www.comicvine.com/neyaphem/65-45565/)

> Led by Azazel, the **Neyaphem** are a group of mutants with demonic appearances. **Existing since biblical times**, the Neyaphem believed humans to be inferior and should be used and/or killed.

That definitely makes him not the first (IIRC he ws born in 1920?) by something like a couple of millenia?

How can this be reconciled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Marvel's claim of Namor being the first mutant only works when looking at the timeline of created/published mutants.

He was created for Motion Picture Funnies Weekly in 1939, but was not actually introduced until Marvel Comics #1 the same year.

Further confusing the issue is the fact that Namor was not originally defined as a mutant. Xavier and Magneto believed him to be a "hybrid" instead of a mutant. It was not until the 90's when Marvel officially declared him as a mutant.

**Marvel's First *Published* Mutant** just doesn't have the same ring to it, but it's technically correct as it's *their* first mutant - just not their oldest one.

Comment: So TL;DR is "First" was meant "in publishing order" and not "oldest"? :)

Comment: And to add to that, Apocalypse was the first mutant. Or at least he used to be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Namor wasn't defined as a mutant, since he was created before the term became popular.  But neither Magneto or Xavier say anything about Namor being a hybrid in X-Men #6, back at the beginning of the Silver Age.  They both say they believe he's a mutant, which is why they both seek him out.  Magneto also asked him to join his Brotherhood of Evil MUTANTS.

Storywise, in the history of the MU, he's also considered the first known mutant to the general public.  Most of the general public don't know about Selene or Apocalypse or other older mutants.

Answer (score 2):

The “First Mutant” title was actually explained in canon not too long ago. I’m having trouble recalling which exact run and issue; but basically in the issue Hank McCoy and his fellow X-Club eggheads need a biological sample from a very early mutant. While searching for mutants old enough and for their sample Namor was brought into question. One of the characters then referred to Namor as “The First Mutant “ and McCoy corrected him. Explaining that there are many mutants older and more ancient than Namor; but the origin of his first mutant moniker is is due to the do to the fact that he was the FIRST mutant birth of the modern day mutant boom and population .

Comment: Hello and welcome, if you could find the issue, this would be an amazing answer!

Answer (score 0):

> It was not until the 90's when Marvel officially declared him as a mutant.

Perhaps officially, but they called him a "mutant" way back in Fantastic Four Annual #1, 1961, ("possibly the first known mutant of our time") before the X-men even existed.

Comment: This does not seem to add anything to the answers already given.